# Is there a way to show KeyBindings with the JMenuBar similar to how is natively shown on MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm using Java Swing to try and build an application that feels as native-y on a Mac as possible. My application has a lot of key binds for the Menu actions, and I want them to display in the Menu Bar similar to how they do in Safari (see screenshot below). Any advice?

[image: 1]

Comment: `JMenuItem` has the [`setMnemonic`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic(int)) and [`setAccelerator `](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke)) methods

Comment: I tried `setMnemonic()` but it didn't show up in the Mac Navbar... would `setAccelerator()` do that? Or is it not possible...

Comment: The accelerator is what you see on the right side of the menu item. The mnemonic is the character in the text that as underlined. The accelerator can be invoked even if the menu is not open. The mnemonic is only active on a visible menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import stackoverflow.Main.TestPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
                fileMenu.setMnemonic('F');
                menuBar.add(fileMenu);

                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("New Window", 'N', KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK)));
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("New Private Window", 'W', KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK)));
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("New Tab", 'T', KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_T, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK)));
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Open File...", 'O', KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK)));
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Open Location...", 'L', KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_L, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK)));
                fileMenu.addSeparator();
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Close Window", 'C', KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK)));
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Close All Windows", 'A', KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK)));
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Close Tab", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK)));
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Save As...", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK)));
                fileMenu.addSeparator();
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Share"));
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Export as PDF..."));
                fileMenu.addSeparator();
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Impory From"));
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Export Bookmarks..."));
                fileMenu.addSeparator();
                fileMenu.add(createMenuItem("Print...", 'P', KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK)));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JMenuItem createMenuItem(String text, char mnemonic) {
        return createMenuItem(text, mnemonic, null);
    }

    public JMenuItem createMenuItem(String text, char mnemonic, KeyStroke keyStroke) {
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(text);
        menuItem.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        menuItem.setAccelerator(keyStroke);
        return menuItem;
    }

    public JMenuItem createMenuItem(String text, KeyStroke keyStroke) {
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(text);
        menuItem.setAccelerator(keyStroke);
        return menuItem;
    }

    public JMenuItem createMenuItem(String text) {
        return new JMenuItem(text);
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

You can also make use of [`Desktop#setDefaultMenuBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#setDefaultMenuBar(javax.swing.JMenuBar)) if you'd like to put it in the "native menu bar"

[image]

```
Desktop.getDesktop().setDefaultMenuBar(menuBar);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

I would recommend becoming familiar with the `Desktop` API, as it will be very helpful for you on the Mac platform